# Port 24 outgoing traffic Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: server

Trying to figure out what causes high outgoing traffic from localhost/24
I can see average 1mbps via ethernet on freshly installed generic intel machine

ufw enabled

`netstat -atupen and netstat -atupen | grep ESTABLISHED`
do not list the port

Comment: Use `sudo lsof -i:24` to see which process has the port open.

Answer (score 0):

alright, got the answer - managed to see the traffic with sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0

it is internal traffic